# Why does my division styling style 2 child elements even though i placed a first-child tag?

Tags: css

So i have a div with 2 columns and images in both of them,and i want only the first image to have a margin.

HTML code:

```
      <div class="column">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="assets/images/images/crop-1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="assets/images/images/sliced-2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS portion:

```
    div.center img:first-child{
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

The only problem is,the first child selector isn't working as intended and styles both of my images and give them a margin...How do i Fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You css isn't working because both of your `img` elements are the first child inside of their parent.
What you maybe want is to add a margin to the image inside of the **first column**.

Something like

```css
    .column:first-child img {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
```

Without seeing the rest of your html i cannot know if this will work correctly. It will only work if the first column is indeed the first child inside its parent.

Another solution would be for you to add classes to your images, something like

```html
<div class="column">
    <div class="center">
        <img class="image image--with-margin" src="assets/images/images/crop-1.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="center">
        <img class="image" src="assets/images/images/sliced-2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

and then

```css
.image--with-margin {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the columns in a container div and target only the first column

html:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="assets/images/images/crop-1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="center">
      <img src="assets/images/images/sliced-2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container .column:first-of-type img {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```